# Magento ver. 2.2.3 Catalog Category URL rewrite

Tags: category, magento2.2.3, catalog-url-rewrite

Some of the catalog category URL are not been generated and are showing URLs as http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/magento223/catalog/category/view/id/111/

this is an issue in only 20 categories and while I have almost 500 categories.

Do we have a checklist for this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin -> Marketing -> UrlRewrites and rewrites grid search for catalog/category/view/id/111/ in target path and check its redirect type if it is set as 302 please set it as no.

Let me know if any help needed.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: @ramkrishan but they are category and if url_key is changed then this also needs to be changed.